# Android: Device Screen not timing out with latest android System WEBVIEW

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

1)Cordova(Webview) based android app.

2)Launch the app and screen times out peoperly as per device settings.

3)From application side we are not acquiring any SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK or ON_AFTER_RELEASE.

4)When app put to background and brought to foreground, device screen light never times out.

4)From application side we are not acquiring any SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK or ON_AFTER_RELEASE.

5)Basically when coming to foreground the PowerManager is acquire ON_AFTER_RELEASE | SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK(0x2000000a) wake-lock on behalf of our app 10311 and screen is kept on.

```
Line 58354: 08-14 22:49:22.280 D/PowerManagerService( 1088): [api] acquire WakeLock flags=0x2000000a tag=WindowManager uid=1000 pid=1088

08-14 22:50:22.000 I/PowerManagerService( 1088): [PWL]  SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK        'WindowManager' ON_AFTER_RELEASE (uid=1000, pid=1088, ws=WorkSource{10311}) (elapsedTime=59719)
```

6)Starting Android System WebView 59.0.3071.25 beta(Fails to work) ( May 4, 2017)

https://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/android-system-webview/android-system-webview-59-0-3071-25-release/android-system-webview-59-0-3071-25-android-apk-download/

screen timeout issue is seen.

7) Issue is not seen android 7.0 which uses chrome v59 as webview.

Device used: Note 4(5.0.1)

Webview version: 59.0.3071.125

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use this plugin:

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin

```
window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake() to keep the screen awake
window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain() to allow sleep again
```

Comment: Have tried this myself(clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)) and fails to work.. https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin/blob/master/src/android/nl/xservices/plugins/Insomnia.java

Comment: When app put to background and brought to foreground, device screen light never times out: Did you try to call window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain() after the application is brought back to foreground? Seems to work for me...

Comment: Plugin does this getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);  have tired the same myself and nothing happens.